# how do i acess data in a Json file with arrays in php and echo to html file

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi I have an json file that include a field of array named urlPhotos. I would like to have a list for urlPhotos om my html page using the echo method in PHP

my data in the json file has this structure

```
[{
    "caseKey": "4846ccde-8e2c-4360-9381-9d78c12b1ef6",
    "caseNumber": "177",
    "companyName": "Bach",
    "officeId": 37,
    "urlPhotos": [
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f868e-9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/520-80276a.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86763c9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86636fd8.jpg"           
    ],

    "timestamp": "09022018073555"
}
{
    "caseKey": "4846ccde-8e2c-4360-9381-9d78c12baaa",
    "caseNumber": "199",
    "companyName": "Bach",
    "officeId": 37,
    "urlPhotos": [      
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f868e-9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/520-80276a.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86763c9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86636fd8.jpg"
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f868e-9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/520-80276a.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86763c9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86636fd8.jpg"       
        ],
    "timestamp": "11022018073555"
}]
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, welcome to StackOverflow Please keep in mind that SO is not a code writing service and we expect question askers to provide the code they are having a specific problem with, you can read more about improving your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode the json array with `json_decode` to normal php array and then use the foreach on this array to get `urlPhotos` like

```
foreach($arr['urlPhotos'] as $t)
{
    echo $t
}
```

And you can add `list` marks to this foreach

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must fetch the json file contents into PHP. One way of doing it:

`$contents = file_get_contents(<your-file-name>);`

Then you must convert this raw JSON string into a JSON object. As the json is an array, you will get an array:

`$jsonArray = json_decode($contents);`

Then looping through this array is how you reach the **urlPhotos**:

```
foreach($jsonArray as $o){
  foreach($o->urlPhotos as $photo){
    echo $photo . "<br>";    
  }
}
```

This code above would loop the array and grab every object. Then within each object you have a urlPhotos property, which is an array that you can use in any way you want. In this case we are looping through every photo and as you commented above we are **echoing** its contents via `php echo`.

Comment: @MarSkayff Have you tried your code? I t does not  work

Comment: @GNETODOMINIQUE - Yeah, you are right. Had a little bug. Corrected.

Answer (score -1):

See this script below . I have used pure `javascript` along with `Jquery`.But you can use only javascript.

> Your data was not well formatted , it was missing comma between each main curly brace, and a comma in urlPhotos array

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#clickme").click(function(){
          getPhotoUri(MyUris);
        }); 
    });

var MyUris = [
    {
       "caseKey": "4846ccde-8e2c-4360-9381-9d78c12b1ef6",
       "caseNumber": "177",
       "companyName": "Bach",
       "officeId": 37,
       "urlPhotos": [
           "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f868e-9.jpg", 
           "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/520-80276a.jpg", 
           "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86763c9.jpg", 
           "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86636fd8.jpg"           
       ],
     "timestamp": "09022018073555"
    }, //here you did not put a comma

   {
     "caseKey": "4846ccde-8e2c-4360-9381-9d78c12baaa",
     "caseNumber": "199",
     "companyName": "Bach",
     "officeId": 37,
     "urlPhotos": [      
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f868e-9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/520-80276a.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86763c9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86636fd8.jpg",
        //here you did not put a comma 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f868e-9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/520-80276a.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86763c9.jpg", 
        "https://boligsystem.flex.dk/public/569f86636fd8.jpg"           
        ],

    "timestamp": "11022018073555"
   }
]

function getPhotoUri(arr){
    for(i=0; i <arr.length; i++ ){
        for(y=0; y < arr[i].urlPhotos.length; y++){
            $("#urlphoto").append(arr[i].urlPhotos[y] + "<br> ");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="clickme">Get your photo</button> 
    <h2> LIST OF YOUR URL PHOTO.</h2>
    <p id="urlphoto"> </p>
```